# ASP.NET UpdatePanel timer updated losing focus on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 UpdatePanels on my screen. One has a textbox in it and another is a gridview. I have a timer (outside of the UpdatePanel) that refreshes the gridview every 5 seconds. The UpdatePanel that has the textbox in it has a button (outside of the UpdatePanel) and when pressed what is entered in the textbox gets added to the DB and the textbox gets clear out, all via the UpdatePanel (ajax, no page loads).

The issue I have is when the UpdatePanel that is linked to the timer and refreshing the gridview does it's thing it steals focus away from the textbox. I can give it focus by adding codebdehind "System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).SetFocus(this.txtNewComment);" but that places the cursor at the begining of the textbox. If I'm in the middle of typing something it screws up what I'm typing because the cursor is at the begining and not the end.

Any ideas on how to keep the cursor exactly where it is in the textbox when the timer triggers the UpdatePanel?

Normally you'd use the `Select()` function of the textbox as described here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349.aspx) but Select() doesn't seem to exist in ASP.NET for MS buttons.

Comment: Is your Timer inside the UpdatePanel with the Gridview?  Or is it outside of both UpdatePanels? If it is outside both, try putting it inside the UpdatePanel with the GridView.

Comment: No change if I place the Timer inside the UpdatePanel that the GridView is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting to both UpdatePanels the attribute `UpdateMode="Conditional"`.

In the following example the textbox doesn't lose focus.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TextBoxUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="PanelTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="TimeLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Timer ID="myTimer" runat="server" OnTick="myTimer_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack) {
        PanelTextBox.Focus();
        myTimer.Interval = 3000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    TimeLiteral.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So this works, but why does setting UpdateMode to Conditional (that's all I did. I didn't change my codebehind to what you have.) have anything to see with the focus and cursor position in this situation? I don't get it.

Comment: When the timer ticks, by default all the UpdatePanels in the page will refresh. Setting the UpdateMode to Conditional changes this behaviour.

Comment: Oh wait, the default must be "Always" which looks like all UpdatePanels will get updated when any of them do. Which is causing my textbox that is in a different updatepanel to get updated hence losing focus. That seems strange they would even have that "feature". Must be more related to nested UpdatePanels

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextBox outside UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PanelTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TextBoxUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```